# How to display GIF Image from URL in UWP using XAML?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I want to display this GIF from the following URL in my app:

[Click here](http://api.wunderground.com/api/9270a990901ad2ce/animatedradar/animatedsatellite/image.gif?num=5&delay=50&rad.maxlat=47.709&rad.maxlon=-69.263&rad.minlat=31.596&rad.minlon=-97.388&rad.width=640&rad.height=480&rad.rainsnow=1&rad.reproj.automerc=1&rad.num=5&sat.maxlat=47.709&sat.maxlon=-69.263&sat.minlat=31.596&sat.minlon=-97.388&sat.width=640&sat.height=480&sat.key=sat_ir4_bottom&sat.gtt=107&sat.proj=me&sat.timelabel=0&sat.num=5)

I cannot implement this through the conventional process, it's just showing an image without any animations.

Comment: It might  be the problem of ur app to show the gif,because browsers normally support the GIF format

Comment: GIFs and Animated GIFs are only supported in Anniversary Update and Above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's not working for you but I quickly made a demo project and the GIF shows fine.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Image Height="200" Width="200" Source="{x:Bind ImageSource, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private string ImageSource { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            ImageSource = @"http://api.wunderground.com/api/9270a990901ad2ce/animatedradar/animatedsatellite/image.gif?num=5&delay=50&rad.maxlat=47.709&rad.maxlon=-69.263&rad.minlat=31.596&rad.minlon=-97.388&rad.width=640&rad.height=480&rad.rainsnow=1&rad.reproj.automerc=1&rad.num=5&sat.maxlat=47.709&sat.maxlon=-69.263&sat.minlat=31.596&sat.minlon=-97.388&sat.width=640&sat.height=480&sat.key=sat_ir4_bottom&sat.gtt=107&sat.proj=me&sat.timelabel=0&sat.num=5";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You most likely would want `OneWay` mode added to your `x:Bind` also.

Comment: OneWay or OneTime doesn't matter unless you also add a change notification to the ImageSouce property.

Comment: Thank you! it works
Another query: I am trying to define image using the url
 BitmapImage i2 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://api.wunderground.com/api/9270a990901ad2ce/radar/image.gif?centerlat=38&centerlon=-96.4&radius=100&width=280&height=280&newmaps=1", UriKind.Absolute));
I want to define and insert my custom centerlat and centerlon by modifying above bitmapimage syntax ,I tried to parse parameters lat and lon using string.format that doesn't work.Thanks!